# How to unit test this Angular typescript Http Error Interceptor that catches errors from a piped observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, rxjs

I am running an experiment where I am learning angular and typescript via testing  someone else code (e.g. automated unit and end to end tests). After I get it under test, I plan to repurposes it for a pet project I am working on for a university classroom.

I am at least half way through unit testing the code from here: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/16/angular-6-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

I have been trying for some time to get the following code under unit test but everything I have tried from my own ideas or ideas from the internet have been unsuccessful thus far:

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from "@angular/common/http";
import { AuthenticationService } from "src/app/authenticationService/AuthenticationService";
import { Observable, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { catchError } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        console.log('before error handle')
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {

            console.log('in error handle')

            if (err.status === 401) { 
                // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
                this.authenticationService.logout();
                location.reload(true);
            }

            const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
            return throwError(error);
        }))
    }

}
```

The following test code and several variations have been unsuccessful to get the 'in error handle' message to show up in the console log:

```
import { ErrorInterceptor } from "./ErrorInterceptor";
import { of, throwError, defer } from "rxjs";

describe('ErrorInterceptor', () => {
    let errorInterceptor;
    let authenticationServiceSpy;

    beforeEach(() => {
        authenticationServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('AuthenticationService', ['logout']);
        errorInterceptor = new ErrorInterceptor(authenticationServiceSpy);
    })

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(errorInterceptor).toBeTruthy();
    })

    describe('intercept', () => {
        let httpRequestSpy;
        let httpHandlerSpy;
        const error = {status: 401, statusText: 'error'};

        it('should auto logout if 401 response returned from api', () => {
            //arrange
            httpRequestSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpRequest', ['doesNotMatter']);
            httpHandlerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpHandler', ['handle']);
            httpHandlerSpy.handle.and.returnValue({
                pipe: () => {
                return fakeAsyncResponseWithError({});
                }
            });

            //act
            errorInterceptor.intercept(httpRequestSpy, httpHandlerSpy);

            //assert
            //TBD

            function fakeAsyncResponseWithError<T>(data: T) {
                return defer(() => throwError(error));
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A couple of issues here.

- First, your return value from `httpHandlerSpy.handle()` needs to be an Observable, since that will already have the pipe operator on it and then the HttpInterceptor code can pipe it to catchError as required.
- Second, HttpInterceptor returns an Observable and for this to be "executed", it needs to be subscribed to.

I put together a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53672234-jqwk3u?file=app%2FErrorInterceptor.spec.ts) to demonstrate how I'd approach this.

From the Stackblitz, here is the spec (`it` function):

```
it('should auto logout if 401 response returned from api', () => {
    //arrange
    httpRequestSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpRequest', ['doesNotMatter']);
    httpHandlerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpHandler', ['handle']);
    httpHandlerSpy.handle.and.returnValue(throwError(
        {error: 
            {message: 'test-error'}
        }
    ));
    //act
    errorInterceptor.intercept(httpRequestSpy, httpHandlerSpy)
        .subscribe(
            result => console.log('good', result), 
            err => { 
                console.log('error', err);
                expect(err).toEqual('test-error');
            }
        );

    //assert

})
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Really appreciate it. Thanks! It not only answered my question thoroughly and succinctly but taught some things in the process with some runnable demo code.

Comment: This answer was helpful for me also. Thanks :-)

Comment: @dmcgrandle, can you please answer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63555118/how-to-unit-test-an-error-interceptor-in-angular-usig-karma-and-jasmine?noredirect=1#comment112386417_63555118

I've 2 private methods along with it.

Comment: this use of subscribe and throwError is deprecated in current version, do you have updated suggestions? I'm working to find a updated code

Comment: This helps! I kept putting all my Asserts inside of the `err` function, and they wouldn't fail appropriately. But placing them below your comment `//assert` made all the difference.